# Equality of two populations

Tags: finite-population

Let's have two populations $A$ and $B$. Each population has $n$ integers, where $n>=1$. Can you claim that if means are the same, i.e. $\mu_A=\mu_B$ and so is the variance $\sigma^2_A=\sigma^2_B$ then $A=B$ (i.e. both contain the *same* elements)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, one can't claim this for the general case.
$X$ and $Y=2\mu-X$ have the same variance (easy to prove).
You can then easily build a counter-example for this claim.

Example :   `[1,6,8,9]` can be turned into `[3,4,6,11]` by this process (this is like a symmetry across the mean). Both mean ($\mu=6$) and variance are unchanged.